# Input not sending updates values to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, input

If I insert values into HTML inputs, the new values are not passed to the JavaScript function. If I define the input value attribute is passed and processed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  Name: <input type="text" id="txtName" value="foo" /> Surname:
  <input type="text" id="txtSurname" value="bar" /> Year Born:<input type="number" id="txtYearborn" value="2000" /> Job: <input type="text" id="txtJob" value="work" />

  <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('infoprinted').innerHTML = person1.printAll();">Click </button>

  <p id="infoprinted"> </p>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    function personDescription(name, surname, yearborn, job) {
      this.name = name;
      this.surname = surname;
      this.yearborn = yearborn;
      this.job = job;
      this.printAll = function() {
        return this.name + " " + this.surname + " and he was born in " + this.yearborn + " and her job is " + this.job
      };
    };
    var firstName = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById('txtSurname').value;
    var born = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtYearborn').value);
    var theJob = document.getElementById('txtJob').value;

    var person1 = new personDescription(firstName, lastName, born, theJob);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code only runs once when the page is opened. You need to put your selection code in a function and call it from your button click.

Answer (score 0):

Its expected behavior, as the variables are initialized at page load when the value in the input's is empty.

*HTML*

```
<button type="button" onclick="printAll();">Click </button>
```

*Script*, Create a new function and create `person1` in onclick event handler

```
function printAll(){
    var firstName = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById('txtSurname').value;
    var born = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtYearborn').value);
    var theJob = document.getElementById('txtJob').value;

    var person1 = new personDescription(firstName, lastName, born ,theJob);

    document.getElementById('infoprinted').innerHTML = person1.printAll();
}
```

```js
function personDescription(name, surname, yearborn, job) {
  this.name = name;
  this.surname = surname;
  this.yearborn = yearborn;
  this.job = job;
  this.printAll = function() {
    return this.name + " " + this.surname + " and he was born in " + this.yearborn + " and her job is " + this.job
  };
};

function printAll() {
  var firstName = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
  var lastName = document.getElementById('txtSurname').value;
  var born = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtYearborn').value);
  var theJob = document.getElementById('txtJob').value;

  var person1 = new personDescription(firstName, lastName, born, theJob);

  document.getElementById('infoprinted').innerHTML = person1.printAll();
}
```

```html
Name: <input type="text" id="txtName" value="foo" /> Surname:
<input type="text" id="txtSurname" value="bar" /> Year Born:<input type="number" id="txtYearborn" value="2000" /> Job: <input type="text" id="txtJob" value="work" />

<button type="button" onclick="printAll();">Click </button>

<p id="infoprinted"> </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make it simple like this...

```js
function printAll() {
    var name = document.getElementById('txtName').value;
    var surname = document.getElementById('txtSurname').value;
    var yearborn = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtYearborn').value);
    var job = document.getElementById('txtJob').value;
    return name + " " + surname + " and he was born in " + yearborn + " and her job is " + job;
};
```

```html
Name: <input type = "text" id = "txtName" value = "foo"/>
Surname: <input type = "text" id = "txtSurname" value = "bar"/>
Year Born: <input type = "number" id = "txtYearborn" value = "2000"/>
Job: <input type="text" id = "txtJob" value = "work"/>
<button type="button" onclick = "document.getElementById('infoprinted').innerHTML=printAll();"> Click</button>
<p id = "infoprinted"> </p>
```

One more thing, if you just want to show some values in the input fields as an example, you can use placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
Name: <input type="text" id="txtName" value="foo"/>
Surname:<input type="text" id="txtSurname" value="bar"/>
Year Born:<input type="number" id="txtYearborn" value="2000"/>
Job: <input type="text" id="txtJob" value="work"/>
<button type="button" onclick="printAll()">Click </button>
<p id="infoprinted"> </p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function printAll(){
    var firstName = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById('txtSurname').value;
    var born = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtYearborn').value);
    var theJob = document.getElementById('txtJob').value;
    document.getElementById('infoprinted').innerHTML = firstName+ " " + lastName + " and he was born in "+born + " and her job is " + theJob;
} </script></body></html>
```